Material UI Circular Progress
I'm trying to use loading button with MUI circular linear progress (spinner) but for some reason the spinner itself is turning around button.
Any ideas?
Screenshot of the issue
import SaveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Save';
import LoadingButton from '@mui/lab/LoadingButton';
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import * as React from 'react';





export default function SpecialTasksMain(props) {

    return (
        <div style={{ marginTop: '100px' }}>
            <Paper elevation={3} sx={{ minHeight: '600px' }}>
                <Typography variant="h4" component="h2" sx={{ padding: '10px' }}>
                    Special Tasks
                </Typography>
                <Container maxWidth="xxl">
                    <LoadingButton
                        loading
                        loadingPosition="start"
                        startIcon={<SaveIcon />}
                        variant="outlined"
                    >
                        Save
                    </LoadingButton>
                </Container>
            </Paper>
        </div>
    )

}

I tried to look for css but couldn't find something.

Could you provide the code that you've written so we can assist you?

Can you add button here in which you want to use spinner?

Perhaps the "Container" surrounding your LoadingButton is affecting the position of the spinner. It appears that your container is set to "xxl," but in the MUI documentation, there is no maxWidth property labeled "xxl." Try setting the property to "xl".

Hi @RedEnum, it happens in any case (event under)

I copied your snippet into StackBlitz, and it's functioning properly. Perhaps there's a global CSS property overriding a property of the LoadingButton. Take another thorough look at your CSS to see if there are any "!important" statements. If there's a connection to the button, could you share the snippet so I can offer further assistance?

Same as above........works fine for me too for lg size screen
